# How to turn a 3-column grid into a 4-column grid

Tags: css

I have a 3 column grid that I want to turn into a 4 column grid.

I'm having trouble editing the css, it seems to kind of work but gets broken after a few lines.

This is the current css for 3 columns:

```css
.post-layout.grid .sp-col-4:nth-of-type(3n+1){
  clear:both;
}
.post-layout.grid .post-meta .sp-col-4:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  clear:none;
}
.post-layout.full-grid .sp-col-4:nth-of-type(3n+2){
  clear:both;
}
.post-layout.full-grid .post-meta .sp-col-4:nth-of-type(3n+2){
  clear:none;
}
```

How can I edit this so that it works with 4 columns?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Can you sure the HTML so we can see the structure and what you want to achieve?

Comment: The clear property only applies to floats, so it appears that you are using floats for your layout, which are very antiquated at this point and are much harder to use than flexbox or css grid, both of which are designed for this purpose, whereas floats are designed instead for text layout.  I would use flexbox or css grid instead; it would save you and future maintainers some hassle and make the layout work better on different devices.  You could also use inline-block if you prefer.  Basically, any of these options is better than float for making grids.

Comment: As well as including sample HTML so we can see your structure, and putting a tag into your question which tells us what pre processor you are using, please describe what its working would mean.

Comment: 4columns ? and nth-child(xn) ? start from :nth-child(4n ) , not 3 ;) example : https://jsfiddle.net/x8zw6hcp/